# Matrix dependent on values of <a,b,c>

Tags: linear-algebra, cross-product

Let $v = <a, b, c>$. Find, if possible, a 3-by-3 matrix $M$ so that $Mw = v × w$. Your matrix $M$ will depend on the
values $a, b, c$.

What is the rank of $M$? Column space? Null space? Nullity?

I really have no idea where to start.

Comment: Hint: a matrix is completely determined by its operations on the basis vectors.

Comment: How would I go about computing that?

Comment: What's $v\times\hat i$? How about $v\times\hat j$ and $v\times\hat k$?

Comment: I'm not sure what i, j, or k are. So I don't know how to find their cross product.